# Exception vs raise_application_error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following procedure:

```
     procedure insert_header(p_push_date          in date,
                                p_source_serial      in varchar2,
                                p_source_start_date  in date,
                                p_source_end_date    in date
                                ) is

      id_temp number;

      begin
        -- check for errors
        if p_push_date is null
        then
          result_code := 9213;
          --raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'push_date cannot be null');
        elsif p_source_serial is null
        then
          result_code := 9333;
          --raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'source_serial cannot be null');


        end if;

        -- if there are no errors, do insert
        if result_code is null
        then
          -- fetch sequence number
          id_temp := header_seq.nextval;
          result_code:=0;

      open o_cur_results for
      select id_temp as id
      from dual;

/*insert into*/
        end if;
```

Commit;
end;

When some invalid parameter is inserted, the procedure should not show any popup error window. Instead, it should only return result_code variable.

Could someone show how to do this?

Comment: So what do you want to happen when the parameter validation checks fail?

Comment: I want that the procedure continues to run, and not stop. I want that failed parameter is inserted in log, but that the procedure continues to execute.

Comment: You have only posted a section of your code so it is hard to offer concrete advice. Specifically you have redacted whatever part of the procedure uses the parameters, so we can't tell how the procedure might break. As it stands, with what you've posted it's hard to see that you need do more than invoke your logging package at the two points where you've commented out the `raise_application_error()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Formatted on 4/23/2019 8:17:42 AM (QP5 v5.256.13226.35538) */
PROCEDURE insert_header (p_push_date           IN     DATE,
                         p_source_serial       IN     VARCHAR2,
                         p_source_start_date   IN     DATE,
                         p_source_end_date     IN     DATE,
                         result_code              OUT NUMBER)
IS
   id_temp   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- check for errors
   IF p_push_date IS NULL
   THEN
      result_code := 9213;
      RETURN;
   --raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'push_date cannot be null');
   ELSIF p_source_serial IS NULL
   THEN
      result_code := 9333;
      RETURN;
   --raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'source_serial cannot be null');
   END IF;
   -- if there are no errors, do insert
   IF result_code IS NULL
   THEN
      -- fetch sequence number
      id_temp := header_seq.NEXTVAL;
      result_code := 0;

      OPEN o_cur_results FOR SELECT id_temp AS id FROM DUAL;
   /*insert into*/
   END IF;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: What do you think RETURN does here?

Comment: When some invalid parameter is inserted, the procedure should not show any popup error window. Instead, it should only return result_code variable. How to do that?

Comment: @user11153823 - please **edit your question** to include a complete requirement. A simple way to do this would be to list some sample calls of your procedure with different combinations of parameters and your desired output for each case.